# Find all $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n) + f\big(f(n)\big) = 6n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, recurrence-relations, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $$f(n) + f\big(f(n)\big) = 6n$$
> for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I don't know any formal way to solve this. I just tried to use some functions of the form $f(n) =\alpha n$ and found that $f(n) = 2n$ is the answer because $2n + 2(2n) = 6n$

I don't know how to correctly solve this type of questions and just used simple try-error method, So any help on solving this in mathematical way is appreciated.

I am not also sure about the tags I selected. It looks like a number theory problem to me that is also related to recurrence relations. Sorry if the tag is inappropriate.

Comment: Very similar problem [if $f(f(n))+f(n)=2n$ find $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929775)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prove that $$f^{k}(n)+f^{k-1}(n)-6\,f^{k-2}(n)=0$$
for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$. Here, $f^0:=\text{id}_\mathbb{N}$ and $f^k:=f\circ f^{k-1}$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$.  Use a result from recursive sequences to show that
$$f^k(n)=2^k\,A(n)+(-3)^k\,B(n)$$
for some functions $A,B:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$.  Verify that $B$ is identically zero.

> Anyhow, it would be a very interesting problem to find all $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$f\big(f(n)\big)+f(n)-6n=0$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  There are at least two solutions $f(n)=2n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $f(n)=-3n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. We have seen so far that $$f^{k}(n)=2^k\,\left(\frac{3n+f(n)}{5}\right)+(-3)^k\,\left(\frac{2n-f(n)}{5}\right)$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Are there more such functions?

Comment: How do you find your initial equality without assuming $f$ is linear?

Comment: I do not apply $f$ on the whole equation (this is what I believe what you were referring to).  I simply replace $n$ by, for example, $f(n)$.

Comment: Ahh... fair enough.

Comment: @Aqua  Did you read the hidden box, where I gave explicitly $A(n)$ and $B(n)$ in terms of $f(n)$ and $n$?

Comment: @Aqua What happens if there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)\ne 2n$?  Recall that $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, so it cannot take a negative value.

Comment: @Aqua  I thought you were talking about the original question.  If you were talking about the proposed question in the hidden box, where $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, I don't know if there are other solutions apart from $f(n)=2n$ and $f(n)=-3n$.  The formula for $f^k$ was given because it may be (or may not be) useful to people who wanted to try.

Comment: @Aqua, I mean, there actually exists another solution (I think somebody told me about it, not sure who, not sure where).  That solution is $f(n)=2n$ if $n$ is even, and $f(n)=-3n$ if $n$ is odd.  No further solutions are known.

Comment: @Aqua  For the general setting ($f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$), there is no reason why $A(n)$ or $B(n)$ should be $0$.

Comment: @Aqua If $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, then $B(n)$ has to be $0$.

Comment: @Aqua If not $(-3)^k\,B(n)$ will overcome $2^k\,A(n)$ for some large $k$, making $f^k(n)$ negative.