# Determine all functions $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f\big(f(n)\big)=-(q-p)\,f(n)+pq\,n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, functional-equations, recursion, integers

Let $p$ and $q$ be integers.  Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, and $f:S\to S$.  Consider the functional equation of the form
$$f\big(f(n)\big)=-(q-p)\,f(n)+pq\,n\text{ for each }n\in S\,.\tag{*}$$
If $p$ and $q$ satisfy $0<p<q$, and $S=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ or $S=\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, then the only solution is known to be
$$f(n)=pn\text{ for all }n\in S\,.$$
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3391328/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929775/) for references.

The case of my particular interest is when $S=\mathbb{Z}$.  We know that there are at least two solutions:
$$f(n)=pn\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$f(n)=-qn\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{Z}\,.$$

> Are there other solutions when $S=\mathbb{Z}$?

What happens if $p<q$ does not hold (but they are still positive integers)?  What can happen if we simply allow $p$ and $q$ to be any integer?  How would these changes affect the cases $S=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $S=\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, and $S=\mathbb{Z}$?  (For example, when $p=1$ and $q=-1$, then there can be other solutions such as $f(n)=n+1$ for all $n\in S$.)

If you feel particularly enthusiastic today, then you can also consider the case where $p$ and $q$ are nonintegral, not necessarily real, algebraic integers such that $q-p$ and $pq$ are both integers.  In this version of the problem (except for a few pairs $(p,q)$), I do not expect a solution in any of the cases $S=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $S=\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, and $S=\mathbb{Z}$.

The trivial case $p=q=0$ is completely solved.  Other known trivial cases are $p=q=1$ and $p=q=\sqrt{-1}$.  However, I do not know other results even when $p=q$.

***[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027239) is a nontrivial example for a nonintegral pair $(p,q)$.***  When $S=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ or $S=\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, there exists a strictly increasing function $f:S\to S$ such that $$f\big(f(n)\big)=3n\text{ for all }n\in S\,.$$  (This is an example when $p=q=\sqrt{3}$.)

> This may be (or may not be) helpful.  Here, $f^0:=\text{id}_S$ and $$f^k:=f\circ f^{k-1}$$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$.  If $p+q\neq 0$, then $$f^k(n)=p^k\,\left(\frac{qn+f(n)}{p+q}\right)+(-q)^k\,\left(\frac{pn-f(n)}{p+q}\right)$$ for all $n\in S$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  On the other hand, if $q=-p$ and $p\neq 0$, $$f^{k}(n)=p^k\,n+k\,p^{k-1}\,\big(f(n)-pn\big)$$ for all $n\in S$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: The "hide" capability is for the Puzzle and pop culture forums, where it serves to prevent spoilers. It has no purpose in forums like this one other than to be annoying.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I disagree. As a rule, use of the "hide" capability does not annoy me on this forum ; as in this case, I sometime use it to indicate something that a hasty reader may skip on first reading

Comment: Are you already aware of solutions like  $p=2,q=3,f(n)=\begin{cases} 2n \text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
-3n\text{ if } n \text{ is odd}\end{cases}$

Comment: @AngelaRichardson  I was not aware, but please feel free to put your example as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution: $p=2,q=3,f(n)=\begin{cases} 2n \text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
-3n\text{ if } n \text{ is odd}\end{cases}$

Use the  technique from your first link, it can be shown that all solutions to the functional equation are of the form $f(n)=\begin{cases} pn \text{ if } n\in T\\
-qn\text{ if } n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus T \end{cases}$

Write $f(f(…(n)..)$ as $f^k(n)$. Then $f^k(n)=-(q-p)f^{k-1}(n)+pqf^{k-2}n$. This is a linear recurrence equation and [standard techniques](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html) yield a solution of the form $f^k(n)=A(n)p^kn+B(n)(-q)^kn$. Substituting back into the original functional equation tells us that $A+B=1+2AB$. The only integer solutions are $A=1,B=0$ and $A=0,B=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below considers the easiest case where $p=q=\sqrt{b}$ (where $b$ is an integer) and aims to provide the complete solution of this particular sub-problem.

We are looking for functions $f:S\to S$ satisfying the equality $$f\left(f\left(n\right)\right)=b\cdot n$$
for all $n\in S$, where $S$ is a fixed, non-empty set of integers. It is obvious that $S$ must be closed under multiplication by $b$, so this will be assumed from now on.

Evaluating the expression $f\left(f\left(f\left(n\right)\right)\right)$ in two different ways gives us a useful property of $f$:

$$f\left(b\cdot n\right) =
f\left(\ f\left(f\left(n\right)\right)\ \right) =
f\left(f\left(\ f\left(n\right)\ \right)\right) =
b\cdot f(n)
$$

which must be satisfied for every $n\in S$.

Now, we are ready to resolve a few special cases:

- $b=0$

  If $T$ denotes the set of integers mapped to zero by $f$, any integer $n\in\left(S-T\right)$ must be mapped to a number from $T$ in order to satisfy $f\left(f\left(n\right)\right)=0$. Since $f(0)=f(0\cdot 0)=0\cdot f(0)=0$, we have $0\in T$. Other than this single restriction, $T$ can be an arbitrary subset of $S$.

  It works the other way round too: If we choose any subset $T$ of $S$ which contains $0$ and any function $g:(S-T)\to (T-\{0\})$, we can define $f$ as
  $$
  f(n)=\begin{cases}
  0 & \textrm{ if }n \in T \\
  g(n) & \textrm{ if }n \in (S-T) \\
  \end{cases}$$
- $b=1$

  We need to satisfy $f\left(f\left(n\right)\right)=n$ which simply says $f$ is an *involution* and it's clear that any involution on $S$ would work.
- $b=(-1)$

  If $S$ contains zero, we have $f(0)=-f(0)$ and thus $f(0)=0$. For any other integer $n\in S$, we can consider the set of $M=\{n, f\left(n\right), f\left(f\left(n\right)\right), f\left(f\left(f\left(n\right)\right)\right), \ldots\}$. Since we have $f\left(f\left(n\right)\right)=(-n)$, we can simplify it to $M=\{n, f(n), (-n), -f(n)\}$.

  None of the numbers in $M$ can be zero (since that would make all of them zero and we assumed $n$ to be non-zero) and $f(n)=\pm n$ would imply $(-n) = f(f(n))=f(\pm n) = \pm f(n) = n$, all four numbers are distinct and exactly two of them must be positive, where one of them is obtained by applying $f$ to the other one.

  This "pairing" of positive integers of $S$ defined by $f$ can be represented by a bijection and, vice versa, if $S^+$ denotes the subset of positive integers within $S$ and we choose any subset $T\subset S^+$ of them and any bijection $g:T\to (S^+-T)$, we can define
  $$
  f(n)=\begin{cases}
  g(n) & \textrm{ if }n \in T \\
  -g^{-1}(n) & \textrm{ if }n \in (S^+-T)\\
  -g(-n) & \textrm{ if }(-n) \in T \\
  g^{-1}(-n) & \textrm{ if }(-n) \in (S^+-T)\\
  0 & \textrm{ if }n=0 \textrm{ (only if $0\in S$)}
  \end{cases}$$

Now we are ready to tackle all the remaining cases. It is easy to see that $f$ must be injective:
$$f(x)=f(y)\implies
f\left(f\left(x\right)\right) = f\left(f\left(y\right)\right) \implies
b\cdot x = b\cdot y \implies
x=y$$

If $0\in S$, we have $f(0)=f(b\cdot 0)=b\cdot f(0)$ which implies the only possible value of $f(0)$ is $0$. For any other integer $n\in S$, we have $f(b\cdot n)=b\cdot f(n)$, and thus also $f(b^k\cdot n)=b^k\cdot f(n)$ for any non-negative integer $k$.

Thus, if $S^*$ denotes the set $$S^* = \{n \in S\ |\ (n/b)\not\in S\}$$ the function $f$ is fully determined if we know its values for members of $S^*$.
For any $n\in S^*$, there are only three possibilities:

- $f(n)=m\in S^*$ and we have $f(m)=b\cdot n$ in order to satisfy $f(f(n))=b\cdot n$, or
- $f(n)=b\cdot m$ for some $m\in S^*$, where we get $f(m)=n$ since $f$ is injective and we have $f(f(m))=b\cdot m=f(n)$, or
- $f(n)=b^2\cdot m$ for some $m \in S$. Again, the injectivity of $f$ implies $f(b\cdot m)=n$, but in this case we also have $f(b\cdot m)=b\cdot f(m)$. This contradicts the choice of $n$ as member of $S^*$.

Thus, $S^*$ consists of pairs of integers for which $f$ maps one member of the pair to the other one (but not vice versa). Just like before, this implies we can construct any function $f$ by considering a set $T\subset S^*$ and a bijection $g:T\to (S^*-T)$ and defining
$$
f(n)=\begin{cases}
b^k\cdot g(m) & \textrm{ if }n=b^k\cdot m\textrm{ with }m\in T \\
b^{k+1}\cdot g^{-1}(m) & \textrm{ if }n=b^k\cdot m\textrm{ with }m\in (S^*-T) \\
0 & \textrm{ if }n=0 \textrm{ (only if $0\in S$)}
\end{cases}$$

This completes the analysis of the $p=q$ case and shows that there are more than enough solutions in each case.

As a specific example, if $b\geq 3$ is odd and $S=\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, we can use the last construction and choose $T$ as the set of positive integers not divisible by $b$ whose leading digit in base-$b$ representation is smaller than $(b/2)$ and $g$ to be a function which increases the leading digit by $\frac{b-1}{2}$. The resulting function $f$ will be strictly increasing and can be extended to $S=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ (by setting $f(0)=0$) or $S=\mathbb{Z}$ (by setting $f(n)=-f(-n)$ for $n<0$) without losing this property.