# Let $f : \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ satisfies $f(f(x)) + f(x) = 6x$. Show that $f(x) = 2x$ only.

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, contest-math, functional-equations, sequence-of-function

> Let $f : \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ satisfies $$f(f(x)) + f(x) = 6x.$$
>
> Show that $f(x) = 2x$ only solution.

I define $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ and $a_0 = x$

Next , I put $x = f^{n-1}(x)$ in the parent equation. This makes the recurrence relation $a_{n+2} + a_{n+1} = 6a_n$.

By using the characteristic root technique, we get $a_n = c_1(2^n) + c_2(-3)^n$. But I don’t know how to use this to make $f(x) = 2x$ only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392386/determine-all-functions-f-mathbbz-to-mathbbz-such-that-f-bigfn-big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're most of the way there!

**Hint:** Show that if $c_2 \neq 0$ , then eventually some $a_n < 0$ ,contradicting $  a_n > 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I get it by setting $c_2 > , < 0$. Both leads to contradiction on some n!

Comment: Yup, that works.

Comment: This would work in general if we have $$f(f(x))+af(x)=bx$$ instead and $a,b$ are any real numbers, such that $f(x)>0$ for each positive $x$?